# combine information from two tables into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to combine information from two tables into one table, the following table is

```
table 1
+----+---------------+---------+
|id_k|   name        |  value  |
+----+---------------+---------+
| 1  | enak          | 4       |
| 2  | nor           | 3       |
+----+---------------+---------+

table 2
+------+------+---------+
| id_d | id_k |  feel   |
+------+------+---------+
|  1   |  1   | good    |
|  2   |  1   | better  |
|  3   |  1   | verygood|
+------+------+---------+
```

result should be

```
+------+------+-------+------------------------+
| id_d | name | value |            feel        |
+------+------+-------+------------------------+
|  1   | enak |   4   | good, better, verygood |
|  2   | nor  |   3   |                        |
+------+------+-------+------------------------+
```

this is my code [not worked]

```
select k.name, k.value, s.feel
from table1 as k 
left join table2 as s on s.id_k=k.id_k
```

Comment: (Dare I ask) why do you want the result formatted this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a7564/1

```
SELECT   t1.id_k, 
  t1.`name`,
  t1.`value`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(t2.feel) AS feel
FROM     table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id_k = t2.id_k
GROUP BY t1.id_k
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`gorup_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to concatinate the values from table2 to a coma-delimited string in the result:

```
SELECT   table1.id_k, name, value, GROUP_CONCAT(feel SEPARATOR ', ') AS feel
FROM     table1
JOIN     table2 ON table1.id_k = table2.id_k
GROUP BY table1.id_k
```